# WifiP2pManager failed to addLocalService and discoverServices returns WifiP2pManager.Error when application is in background

Tags: android, wifi, android-10.0, wifip2p

I'm new here. Anyways I've been scratching my head at this issue I have. I created a service that runs WiFiP2pHelper to discover nearby devices and retrieve WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo. I tested it on multiple phones, and they seem to work fine. If it works fine, it should return logs like these:

```
2020-08-12 13:32:23.449 24345-24345/com.example.acts D/WiFi P2P Helper: Service Request Added
2020-08-12 13:32:23.449 24345-24345/com.example.acts D/WiFi P2P Helper: Discover Services Successful
2020-08-12 13:32:23.473 24345-24345/com.example.acts D/WiFi P2P Helper: Local Service Added
```

Now I made the service to run in the background (even when the application is killed). It seems to work fine on the devices I've tested except any that runs on Android 10. I suspect it's something with Android 10 that causes WiFiP2pManager or WiFi P2P itself not to run in the background. But I'm not entirely sure if it's Android 10 causing it (I only got 2 Android 10 devices that were tested on). It returns the following logs:

```
2020-08-12 13:33:23.517 24345-24345/com.example.acts D/WiFi P2P Helper: Service Request Added
2020-08-12 13:33:23.517 24345-24345/com.example.acts D/WiFi P2P Helper: Error with P2P 0
2020-08-12 13:33:23.518 24345-24345/com.example.acts D/WiFi P2P Helper: Failed to Add Local Service
2020-08-12 13:33:23.518 24345-24345/com.example.acts E/WiFi P2P Helper: 0
```

As you can see, "Error with P2P 0" and "Failed to Add Local Service" points to the discoverServices and addLocalService. Below is the code. Sorry to dump it all here. Any help would really be appreciated! Thanks!

```
public class WiFiP2PHelper extends Service {
    WifiP2pManager manager;
    WifiP2pManager.Channel channel;
    WifiP2pDnsSdServiceRequest serviceRequest;
    IntentFilter intentFilter;
    String iid;
    private String baseServiceName = "ACTS";
    private String serviceName = "";
    final HashMap<String, String> buddies = new HashMap<String, String>();
    final String TAG = "WiFi P2P Helper";
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable;
    int delay = 15000;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        manager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
        channel = manager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);

        intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);

        getUser();
        startRegistration();
        discoverService();
        startMyOwnForeground();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void startMyOwnForeground() {
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "com.example.acts";
        String channelName = "My Background Service";
        NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
        chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        assert manager != null;
        manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setContentTitle("Hello World")
                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                .build();
        startForeground(1333, notification);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private void getUser() {
        List<User> users = User.getUser();
        int count = users.size();
        if (count > 0) {
            User loggedInUser = users.get(0);
            iid = loggedInUser.Id;
            serviceName = baseServiceName + "_" + loggedInUser.Id;
            Log.e("User", iid);
        } else {
            //uId = "User_Unregistered";
            serviceName = baseServiceName + "_User_Unregistered";
            Log.e("User in else", serviceName);
        }
    }

    public String getWFDMacAddress() {
        try {
            List<NetworkInterface> interfaces = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
            for (NetworkInterface ntwInterface : interfaces) {

                if (ntwInterface.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("p2p0")) {
                    byte[] byteMac = ntwInterface.getHardwareAddress();
                    if (byteMac == null) {
                        return null;
                    }
                    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < byteMac.length; i++) {
                        strBuilder.append(String.format("%02X:", byteMac[i]));
                    }

                    if (strBuilder.length() > 0) {
                        strBuilder.deleteCharAt(strBuilder.length() - 1);
                    }

                    return strBuilder.toString().toLowerCase();
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public int findOpenSocket() throws IOException {
        // Initialize a server socket on the next available port.
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(0);
        // Store the chosen port.
        int port = serverSocket.getLocalPort();
        serverSocket.close();
        return port;
    }

    private void startRegistration() {
        manager.clearLocalServices(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Log.e(TAG, "onSuccess: Sucessss");
                int port = 3030;
                try {
                    port = findOpenSocket();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Map record = new HashMap();
                record.put("listenport", String.valueOf(port));
                record.put("buddyname", iid);
                record.put("available", "visible");

                WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo serviceInfo =
                        WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo.newInstance(serviceName, "_presence._tcp", record);
       
                manager.addLocalService(channel, serviceInfo, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Local Service Added");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int arg0) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to Add Local Service");
                        Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(arg0));
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int arg0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "P2P Unsupported");
            }
        });
    }

    private void discoverService() {
        WifiP2pManager.DnsSdTxtRecordListener txtListener = new WifiP2pManager.DnsSdTxtRecordListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDnsSdTxtRecordAvailable(
                    String fullDomain, Map record, WifiP2pDevice device) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DnsSdTxtRecord available - " + record.toString());
                buddies.put(device.deviceAddress, (String) record.get("buddyname"));
            }
        };

        WifiP2pManager.DnsSdServiceResponseListener servListener = new WifiP2pManager.DnsSdServiceResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDnsSdServiceAvailable(String instanceName, String registrationType,
                                                WifiP2pDevice resourceType) {

                resourceType.deviceName = buddies
                        .containsKey(resourceType.deviceAddress) ? buddies
                        .get(resourceType.deviceAddress) : resourceType.deviceName;

                String uId = instanceName.replace(baseServiceName + "_", "");

                Log.d(TAG, "Received " + uId);

                /*Discovered device1 = new Discovered();
                device1.discoveredthreeID = uId;
                Discovered.insertTransactionToSQLite(device1);*/
            }
        };

        serviceRequest = WifiP2pDnsSdServiceRequest.newInstance();
        manager.addServiceRequest(channel,
                serviceRequest,
                new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Service Request Added");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int code) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to Add Service Request");
                    }
                });


        manager.setDnsSdResponseListeners(channel, servListener, txtListener);

        manager.discoverServices(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Discover Services Successful");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int code) {
                // Command failed.  Check for P2P_UNSUPPORTED, ERROR, or BUSY
                if (code == WifiP2pManager.P2P_UNSUPPORTED) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "P2P isn't supported on this device.");
                } else if (code == WifiP2pManager.ERROR) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error with P2P " + code);
                } else if (code == WifiP2pManager.BUSY) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "P2P is Busy " + code);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi everyone who has the same issue as me. I found the solution to this. Basically, Android 10 (API 29) separates location permissions to the normal location permission and background location permission. You'll need to get your application to prompt for background permission (since it's not allowed by default).

Add these to your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

and in my MainActivity onCreate method I added a check to see if the device is on Android 10 (API 29) and if the permissions have already been granted

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) ||
                    (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION}, 1);
            }
        } else {
            if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
            }
        }
```

If anyone else has a better way of implementing permission checks, please share it here. I'd like to learn as well. Thanks!